# Docker - how to dynamically configure an application that uses flat text config files?

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I'm ramping up on Docker and k8s, and am running into an issue with a 3rd party application I'm containerizing where the application is configured via flat text files, without override environment variables.

What is the best way to dynamically configure this app? I'm immediately leaning towards a sidecar container that accepts environment variables and writes the text file config, writes it to a shared volume in the pod, and then the application container will read the config file. Is this correct?

What is the best practice here?

Comment: Would a Kubernetes ConfigMap meet your needs?

Comment: [confd](https://github.com/kelseyhightower/confd) has been written to render flat config-files from environment variables (or other backends). Adding it to your image might be more lightweight than your approach and does not require any volumes. However, a ConfigMap is definitely more standard

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a `ConfigMap` with this configuration file. Then, mount the `ConfigMap` into the pod. This will create the configuration file in mounted directory. Then, you can use this configuration file as usual.

Here are related example:

1. [Create ConfigMap from file](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#create-configmaps-from-files).
2. [Mount ConfigMap as volume](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#add-configmap-data-to-a-volume).

Comment: This looks like a good approach, but I don't see how I can configure multiple pods of the same service to talk to each other. For example, imagine I have 3 nodes of a service that each need to know connection details to talk to the other nodes. Also, say each node has an arbitrary value [1,2,3] (not ip, hostname, etc) that identifies itself, and this value needs to be set in other node's config files. I can't seem to figure out how ConfigMaps help here... am I just designing my services wrong?

Comment: In this case, it is okay to use a shared volume.